# How to fetch data from JSON API into nested Array in React-Native

Tags: react-native

I am trying to fetch data of all attendance attributes from my JSON API.here is my code and JSON API. If there is any easier ways please tell me because i am new in react-native.

```
{
    "message": "30 day data",
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "addEmployee": {
                "firstName": "manisha"
            },
            "attendances": [
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "checkIn": "2020-02-26T09:18:42.000Z",
                    "checkOut": "2020-02-26T09:18:54.000Z",
                    "totalHours": "0:0",
                    "date": "2020-02-26",
                    "status": "present",
                    "createdAt": "2020-02-26T09:18:42.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-02-26T09:18:54.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 4,
                    "checkIn": "2020-02-26T09:19:13.000Z",
                    "checkOut": "2020-02-26T09:20:03.000Z",
                    "totalHours": "0:0",
                    "date": "2020-02-26",
                    "status": "present",
                    "createdAt": "2020-02-26T09:19:13.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-02-26T09:20:03.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "checkIn": null,
                    "checkOut": null,
                    "totalHours": "0",
                    "date": "2020-03-04",
                    "status": "absent",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-04T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-03-04T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 20,
                    "checkIn": null,
                    "checkOut": null,
                    "totalHours": "0",
                    "date": "2020-03-12",
                    "status": "absent",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-12T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-03-12T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 35,
                    "checkIn": null,
                    "checkOut": null,
                    "totalHours": "0",
                    "date": "2020-03-13",
                    "status": "absent",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-13T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-03-13T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 51,
                    "checkIn": null,
                    "checkOut": null,
                    "totalHours": "0",
                    "date": "2020-03-19",
                    "status": "absent",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-19T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-03-19T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 74,
                    "checkIn": null,
                    "checkOut": null,
                    "totalHours": "0",
                    "date": "2020-03-20",
                    "status": "absent",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-20T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-03-20T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                },
                {
                    "id": 92,
                    "checkIn": null,
                    "checkOut": null,
                    "totalHours": "0",
                    "date": "2020-03-23",
                    "status": "absent",
                    "createdAt": "2020-03-23T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "updatedAt": "2020-03-23T13:00:00.000Z",
                    "userId": 3
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "status": 1
}
```

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
 import {
 StyleSheet,
 View,
 Text,
 Image,
 FlatList,
 SafeAreaView,
 ActivityIndicator,


 } from 'react-native';

 export default class Screen4 extends Component {

 constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {
   dataSource: [] ,
   isLoading: true
   }
 }

  renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (


   <View>

   <View style={{height:50,flexDirection:'row',alignItems:'center',}}>
            <Text style={{  fontSize: 15, flex:0.20,  }} > 
          {item.attendances.id}</Text>
             <Text style={{  fontSize: 15, flex:0.20,  }} > 
          {item.attendances.checkIn}</Text>
             <Text style={{  fontSize: 15, flex:0.20,  }} > 
          {item.attendances.checkOut}</Text>
             <Text style={{  fontSize: 15, flex:0.20,  }} > 
          {item.attendances.totalHours}</Text>
             <Text style={{  fontSize: 15, flex:0.25,  }} > 
          {item.attendances.date}</Text>


          </View>
    </View>

    )
    }
  renderSeperator = () => {
  return (
  <View style={{ height: 1, width: '100%', backgroundColor: '#0A5252' }}>
  </View>

  )
 }
  componentDidMount() {
  const url = 'http://104.197.28.169:3000/monthlyAdminData'
  fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

    this.setState({
      dataSource: responseJson.data ,
      isLoading: false
    })
  })
  .catch(error => console.log(error)) 
  }
  render() {
  {
    return (

    this.state.isLoading
      ?
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#330066" />
      </View>
      :
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <SafeAreaView>

        <View style={styles.firstV}>
        <View style={styles.TextV}>

          <Text style={{  fontSize: 15,marginTop: 15, flex:0.20  }}>    ID</Text>

          <Text style={{  fontSize: 15, marginTop: 15, flex:0.20  }}>Check-In</Text>

          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, marginTop: 15, flex:0.22  }}>Check-Out</Text>

          <Text style={{ fontSize: 15, marginTop: 15,flex:0.20  }}> Total hr</Text>

          <Text style={{  fontSize: 15, marginTop: 15, flex:0.20  }}>  date</Text>
        </View>
      </View>

          <FlatList
            data={this.state.dataSource}
            renderItem={this.renderItem}
            keyExtractor={(item, index) => index}
            ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeperator}
          />
        </SafeAreaView>
      </View>

      );
    }
  }
 }
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
  flex: 1,
  backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
},
    firstV: {
     height: 50,
    backgroundColor: '#E5E7E9',

  },
 TextV: {
  flexDirection: 'row',flex:1
  },
  DetailView: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    height: 53,
    borderBottomWidth: 1,
    borderBottomColor: 'black'

  },
   });

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tl2r4.png
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on stackoverflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: @James now let's check my code and API data

Comment: Yout code is perfect. Let us know if you are facing any issue

Comment: @james I just want to fetch data of all attendance attributes like checkIn ,checkOut,totalHours,date,status (which is given above) through APi URL.But this code is not working for me so please make some changes in my code.

Comment: @james i mean i didn't get the data of  item.attendances.id , item.attendances.checkIn , item.attendances.checkOut etc. from above API data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you have an array of objects that themselves contain arrays. So it depends what you want the output to be.

`attendances` is an array, so using `attendances.id` doesn't mean anything. It would have to be `attendances[index].id`

I don't know if this data structure is intentional. If it is (i.e. you want to render nested arrays) then your `renderItem` function needs to contain another `FlatList` with its own `renderAttendancesItem` function where `attendancesDataSource` is `item.attendances` (within your first `renderItem`).

Within that nested `FlatList`'s `renderItem` you could then refer to `item.id`, `item.checkIn` etc etc.

(Alternatively you can parse the JSON you receive into a single array and just use a single FlatList to render the items)

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Glad to help! If you wouldn't mind, please could you mark this as the accepted answer? Thanks!